# Use KML file to detect Countries (Xcode)

Tags: iphone, xml, xcode, parsing, kml

I have a KML file with all the countries and polygons. I am trying to create an app that get a Lat & Lon and detecting in which country belongs using this KML. I tried SimpleKML and KMLViewer with no luck.
The kml structure is:

```
   <Document>
<Folder>
    <Folder>
        <name>A -</name>
        <Placemark>
            <name>Afghanistan</name>
            <description></description>
            <Style>
                <PolyStyle>
                    <color>aaffffff</color>
                    <colorMode>random</colorMode>
                </PolyStyle>
            </Style>
            <Polygon>
                <outerBoundaryIs>
                    <LinearRing>
                        <coordinates>
65.62729644775391,37.33319854736328,0 65.64692687988283,37.45888137817383,0 
...
...

coordinates>
                    </LinearRing>
                </outerBoundaryIs>
            </Polygon>
        </Placemark>
        <Placemark>
            <name>Albania</name>
 ..
 ..
 ..
```

1) It would be better to use xml parser and save the data on a local database?
2)Is there any function to determine in which polygonal is the given lat/lon ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parsing should be pretty easy using NSXMLParser, look for names and associate them with coordinates.  The more interesting part is to test the polygons for inclusion of a point.

[Here's a highly regarded SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217578/point-in-polygon-aka-hit-test), that looks like it borrows somewhat from [this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon).  What you would do is build a collection of polygons, and enumerate them testing each for the inclusion of some given coordinates.

The other thing to think about is to skip the parsing and polygon testing altogether and use the google geocoding api.  [This section talks specifically](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding) about getting address info (including country) from a latitude and longitude.

Comment: It has to be an offline app. So there is no algorithm for lat/lon and polygons?

Comment: not from apple (afaik), but tons of net code.  rolling your own with the ray tracing test doesn't look too awful.  sounds kind of fun, actually.

Comment: So what you suggest? Parse the kml (as xml) and save it as a local database or parse it each time? (I need the fastest way). About algorithm should I use Ray Tracing or Ray Casting?

Comment: It will be faster to save the parse. Whether to use a file or db depends on the polygon count. I don't know which polygon test is faster. I think you've got a big enough challenge just to get it working, and it's wise to make performance decisions only after you have empirical data.

Comment: also - if it's an offline app and you want to be fast, why would you parse at all?  parse before compile time and ship the polygons as literal arrays of floats.

Comment: can you explain the last one please? It's 4MB file.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24283/discussion-between-user776720-and-danh)